# How to specify arguments for a Python api using Kotlin?

Tags: python, android, kotlin, httprequest

I made a python api that I'm trying to get my app to connect to, but for the login function I need to send the username and password but I'm not sure how to do this. This is the python code:

```
        username = data.get('username')
        email = data.get('email')
        password = data.get('password')
```

And the Kotlin Code:

```
    private fun sendData(username:String, password:String): Thread {
        return Thread {
            val url = URL("https://127.0.0.1:5000/login")
            val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
            connection.setRequestProperty("username", username)
            connection.setRequestProperty("password", password)
            if (connection.responseCode == 200) {
                val inputSystem = connection.inputStream
                println(inputSystem.toString())
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "It worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else {
                var code: String = "ERROR"
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "NO CONNECTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

The connection is opened but I can get any data across and I haven't tried anything so far as I can't find good documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, first set up a class to handle your credentials:

```
class LoginData(
    val userID: String,
    val pw: String
){

    /** Returns a hashmap of the data stored in the class object. */
    fun getHashmap(): Map<String,String> {
        val params = HashMap<String,String>()
        params["username"] = userID
        params["password"] = pw
        return params
    }

    /** Obtains a JSONObject of the data stored in the class object. */
    fun getJson(): JSONObject {
        val params = this.getHashmap()
        return JSONObject(params)
    }
}
```

And then, utilising Volley (don't forget to add it to your build gradle: `implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'`), do something like this:

```
 fun sendData(username: String?, password: String?) {

    val url = "https://127.0.0.1:5000/login"

    var loginData = LoginData(
        userID = username!!,
        pw = password!!
    )
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val jsonRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.POST,
        url,
        loginData.getJson(),
        Response.Listener {
                response -> handleResponse(response)//do something with the response
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { error -> println("That didn't work: $error")})
    queue.add(jsonRequest)

}
```

with `handleResponse()` containing your logic to evaluate what comes back from the server:

```
fun handleResponse(response: JSONObject) {
    //your evaluation logic
}
```